# Default Date Format in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

When I create an R Markdown (.Rmd) document, by default the date in the header is in the mm/dd/yyyy format, for example 4/3/2022. I would like to change it so that it displays the full name of the month followed by the year, for example April 2022. Currently, I have to change the date manually once the document is created, but is there some sort of global preference that allows the user to change default date format? I looked through all of the RStudio preferences but I didn't see anything related to the default date format for R Markdown. I also did a quick Google search, but most of the results seem to be focused on generating the date dynamically, whereas I would actually prefer to use the date that the document was created (i.e., static date).

Comment: which header do you mean?

Comment: @hyman The header at the top of the page. For example, at the beginning of every .Rmd file, there is a header section that looks something like:  ```---
title: "STAT 430 Homework 4"
author: "Samuel Erens"
date: "4/3/2022"
output: pdf_document
---``` My question is how can I change it so that the date shows up as April 2022 by default, and more generally how can I customize this header.

Comment: i usually use `date: "`r format(Sys.Date(), '%d.%m.%Y')`" `. Does this not achieve what you want

Comment: @hyman Thanks for the suggestion, but this is not quite what I want. First of all, I want to use a static date (i.e., the date the document was created), not the current/dynamic date. Second, I was wondering if there was a way to change my RStudio/R Markdown preferences so that this date format shows up by default, rather than requiring the date to be manually changed every time I create a new R Markdown document.

Comment: sure, now I understand what you mean. But there is no automatic solution for that I believe. Everything rmarkdown does is in the document.

Comment: Would making a template file with prefilled date format be an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### snippet

*Tools* > *Global Options* > *Code* > *Edit Snippets* or use `usethis::edit_rstudio_snippets()`. Space senstitive!
[image]

Then when starting a new markdown doc, you can insert that snippet.

#### markdown template

For this, we should create a small package and install it.

1. In a directory of choice, run `pkgKitten::kitten("template")`
2. run `usethis::use_rmarkdown_template()`
3. Edit the skeleton.Rmd or .yml file, in inst/rmarkdown/templates/*name/ to your liking. For inspiration or more advanced requirements, the [rticles](https://github.com/rstudio/rticles) repo contains fantastic templates.
4. Optionally add/change default `hello.R` created by pkgKitten. Perhaps create a custom shortcut for thesnippet.
5. Run R CMD check in the build pane.
6. click *install and restart* in the Build pane

Now when you open a new Rmarkdown document you have the option to create from your newly created template

[image]